# PHP setting property that doesn't exist in class works, why? how?

Tags: php, oop

```
<?php

class ser {

    public $a;

}

$x = new ser;
$x->b = 10;

var_dump($x);
```

Something like this.

Class `ser` has only `$a` property, but we can set `$b` to new object of this class and it works despite this class doesn't have any `$b` property

output

```
E:\XAMPP\htdocs\fun\test2.php:12:
object(kurde)[1]
  public 'a' => null
  public 'b' => int 10
```

Why this works?

Why we can add property and set it to this class while it doesn't belong exactly to this class?

How is that possible and why is that possible?

Any purpose? Sense of making this possible?

Comment: Because you can... Aint PHP wonderful

Comment: Why is this allowed? Why we can do this? What is purpose of this and sense? @RiggsFolly

Comment: You can do it in javascript also :) and Python :0 :)

Comment: It's actually quite useful if you're in a framework and you want to pass some extra data with an object for which you might not have a property on that class.

Comment: @Bram if there is a framework, which is built around this behaviour, you probably should stay away from it.

Comment: @tereško That's true, but it's possible if you ever need to :p

Comment: @KrystianPolska it's a common behaviour in many loosely typed languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what PHP refers to as "[overloading](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php)". This is different to overloading in almost any other object oriented language.

If you do not like it, you can use the `__set` magic method to throw an exception if a non-existent property is set:

```
public function __set($name, $value) {
    throw new \Exception('Property "'.$name.'" does not exist')
}
```

You can tell from the comments on the documentation what the general consensus of this "feature" is.